# Button onclick event does not redirect to another page although it calls the functions

Tags: javascript, html

The following code does not redirect to the given webpage

```
<form>
    <button onclick='window.location.replace("../magnet/index.php")'>Replace document</button>
</form>
```

Comment: How about having `"../magnet/index.php"` as action?

Comment: That may work but I want to submit data to other php file and redirect the webpage to some other php file on click of the button.

Comment: You could redirect on the server, or response the request with the file from `../magnet/index.php`. Or use AJAX to send the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is so because when you create a button within the form tags, it is created as a submit button by default. So, instead of redirecting the webpage, it submits the data and reloads the current webpage.

The following code will do the required job because now, the type of the button is button and not submit.

```
<button type="button" onclick='window.location.replace("../magnet/index.php")'>Replace document</button>
```

Comment: "_... but I want to submit data to other php file ..._" This won't submit the form at all.

Comment: To submit the form, we can use another button with type = "submit". Here I wanted two separate buttons, one for submitting the form and the other for opening a new page in case the user has a query while filling the form.

Answer (score 1):

Even better, you can place your redirect code into a JavaScript function. Then you can call that function from within your HTML code. Like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function redirectTo(sUrl) {
window.location = sUrl
}
//-->
</script>
<button onclick="redirectTo('../magnet/index.php')">Get HTML!</button>
```

Hope this will work for you. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to add `type="button"` like **@shivamag00** explained.

But be careful with `replace()`, it's not possible to use "back" to navigate back to the original document since you are replacing the history state.

An alternative is to use the `assign()` function, ([documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Location/assign))

Suppose you have a base url as

```
www.website.come
```

and want to go to

```
www.website.come/new-page
```

it's simple

```html
<button type="button" onclick='window.location.assign("new-page")'>Go to new page</button>
```

It's worked for me, hope it's useful for someone else.